# React storing state in an element variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-state

I want to know how, if possible, I can store a state in an element that is stored in a variable.

This is my simplified code:

```
export class DashboardLists extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        listCount: 0,
        ...
    }

    ...

    this.headerLeft = <h2 style={{marginTop: "0px"}}>Lists {this.state.listCount}</h2>;

    ...
}

render(){
    return(
          <div>
              ...
              {this.headerLeft}
              ...
          </div>
    );
}
}
```

When I call state change, the value in the element doesn't display the updated state value.

It is necessary for me to store the element in a variable, because in my full code I must pass the element as a prop to another element.

Comment: Remove headerLeft from constructor. Create a dedicated method in class, something like `getHeaderLeft() {return <h2 style={{marginTop: "0px"}}>Lists {this.state.listCount}</h2>;}` and call it in render method `{this.getHeaderLeft()}`

Comment: @KonstantinSamarin I have to pass the variable as a prop to another component. Will it still work?

Comment: _"in my full code I must pass the element as a prop to another element"_. That doesn't sound necessary, or maintainable. Why aren't you just importing that component into the other component, or having the parent render it as `children`, or using `context`? There are lots of routes you can take but I don't this is the most suitable.

Comment: @Andy Because I have several different parent components that each have a different `this.headerLeft` variable value

Comment: @JorensM sure, you can

Comment: @KonstantinSamarin Thank you so much, this worked! If you want you can post your answer as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yes but your code says: I have a component that produces many dashboard lists, but there is only one state, and I'm only returning JSX for that component which is a div. But! It sounds like you have lots of lists and you either a) want to maintain state for each of them or b) have `dashboardLists` control the state for each list. Passing a component into the props of another component isn't a solid solution.

Comment: Actually, `DashboardLists` is an extension of the component `DashboardElement`, which has a child `DashboardHeader`, to which I pass the variable. I have a lot of components that extend `DashboardElement` and each of them have different header contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `headerLeft` from constructor. Create a dedicated method in class, something like `getHeaderLeft() {return <h2 style={{marginTop: "0px"}}>Lists {this.state.listCount}</h2>;}` and call it in render method `{this.getHeaderLeft()}`

- Konstantin Samarin